# (Working) String interpolation having localised string Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, localization, swiftui-environment

I am trying to return an interpolated String from a business logic thats return only string type.

I have tried few way but are not useful

```
let value = LocalizedStringKey.init(stringLiteral: "stringKey")
        return ("\(value) \(message)")
```

```
LocalizedStringKey(key:"stringKey",
hasFormatting: false, arguments[])
```

Some suggest to use Text() to get desire result but seems producing similar error

```
text(storage:SwiftUI.Text.Storage.anyTextStorage(SwiftUI
.(unknown context at $7fff5762368).LocalizedTextStorage),
```

Am I missing something here ? Or do we have solution !

Answer (score 0):

Probably you wanted this

```
let value = NSLocalizedString("stringKey", comment: "")
```

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me, so answering here (I am using inside Framework)

```
extension String {
    var getLocaliseValue: String {
        if let frameworkBundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.companyname.FrameworkName") {
          return NSLocalizedString(self, bundle: frameworkBundle, comment: "")
    }
    return ""
}
```

}

usage :

```
"key".getLocaliseValue
```